# How to keep widget configuration after phone restart?

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences

I want to make a widget app that is able to dial a number and user can set the number when he first drag and drop widget to home screen using widget configuration.But when the phone restarts widget uses default number again. I decide to save the entered phonenumber to Shared Preferences to save and load user's phone number but eclipse says that using getSharedPreferences is not allowed in onUpdate.Is there another way to perform it?

What should I do?

my code:

```
public class Main extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for(int i=0 ; i<appWidgetIds.length ; i++)
        {
            SharedPreferences details = getSharedPreferences("OPERATOR", 0);
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String phNumber = "5554574";

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+(phNumber)));
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call your method inside Broadcast receiver.
And in Manifest-
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SharedPreferences details = context.getSharedPreferences("OPERATOR", 0);
```

SharedPreferences has to be acquired from the context. onUpdate(...) provides you the context.

Your changed code should look like this:

```
public class Main extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for(int i=0 ; i<appWidgetIds.length ; i++)
        {
            SharedPreferences details = context.getSharedPreferences("OPERATOR", 0);
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String phNumber = "5554574";

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+(phNumber)));
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        }
    }
}
```

Please try it.

Comment: I save my Shared Preferences like this:

Comment: SharedPreferences details = getSharedPreferences("OPERATOR", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = details.edit();
editor.putString("operator", "hamrah");
editor.commit();

Comment: Yes, it is ok to use, but you have to get SharedPreferences from the Context. AppWidgetProvider is not a Context, so Eclipse shows an error.

Comment: my configuration class is configure.JAVA you mean I should use configure.getshared... but it doesn't recognize that.

Answer (score 0):

AppWidgetProvider is not a Context. But you can often create a static method to reach the context of an application, then do this

In Android Manifest file declare following

```
<application android:name="com.example.MyApplication">

</application>
```

then write the class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
        SharedPreferences details = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("OPERATOR", 0);
```

I haven't worked with widgets yet so can't guarantee this solution but hope it work!